# Parse some website data (SWIFT / JSON)

Tags: json, uitableview, parsing, swift, ios8

I am enjoying putting my toe into the ios swift programming water.  I have been impressed how much can be achieved so quickly but I have come a little confused on how to parse data.  Basically I would like to take the result of the address below and pop it into a tableview:

http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams

I am comfortable with creating and populating a tableview but not sure how I can manipulate the file above to populate the tableview with the "name" and "code" of each entry in the "teams" section from the file.

The tableview should end up with twenty rows with each containing the "name" and "code" of each team in the league.  Note that I put the code in brackets for easier reading: i.e

---

Manchester United FC (MUFC)

---

Swansea City (SWA)

---

Leicester City (LCFC)

---

etc... etc...

I have been pushed in the direction of JSON and SWIFT and had limited success but hoping someone can point me in the right direction or create an example with the link above.

If you feel you need any further information to assist me then please do not hesitate to ask.

Many thanks, Alan.

General Background Information:

The outcome will hopefully be a fun football app to help raise money for a charity I am part of called "Donations With A Difference". Feel free to check us out at https://dwad.org/. I am happy to give credit on the website and within the app for any assistance given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn from this code :

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    let teamsArray = json["teams"] as NSArray

    print("Team List : \(teamsArray)")

    for dic in teamsArray
    {
        let teamname = dic["name"] as NSString

        let code = dic["code"] as NSString

        println("Team Name, \(teamname) : Code, \(code)")
    }
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Extract required content and show up them in UITableView.

Comment: Many thanks for such a swift response.  Really appreciate the help.  I will have a play this evening and try to join my tableview knowledge and the above code.  If you have any links to similar examples then great, if not then not to worry :)

Comment: Hello RoNiT,  If there is anyway I can be cheeky enough to ask for some additional help on linking the json to the tableview I would really appreciate it.  I have spent hours trying but with no joy.  I have asked another question on here but it seems my questions are not specific enough and I am just at a loss.  If you cant offer any more time I understand and appreciate the assistance thus far.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: @AlanTingey There is no shortcut for linking json with tableview. You just have to study tableview to overcome it :)

Comment: i kept going and it finally clicked :)